# How is IEnumerator.ToArray() implemented?

Tags: c#, loops

For `IEnumerator.ToList()`, It seems to be obvious that It will iterate `MoveNext()`, `Add(Current)`, until it meets end.

But for Array, I don't see any clever ways to do it. Without knowing the count of IEnumerator, it will be creating array again and again, increasing it's length by 1 with `MoveNext()` until it meets end. And it would definetly not the way, I'm sure about it.

How is `ToArray()` implemented internally?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L317

Comment: Or more specifically, the actual array creation happens in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Collections/Generic/LargeArrayBuilder.SizeOpt.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic really, and the resultant *buffer* grows the way a `List<T>` does (the exact code depends on the framework you are using and what version), however it's still the same.

1. The *buffer* size will start at size `4` and will increase the size by double each time it needs the capacity. E.g `8, 16, 32, 64, ...`
2. Every time it increases it will use a fast *mem* (style) copy to transfer the data.
3. The final result will *allocate* and *copy* for the size it needs.

Yes, there are *allocations*, and the larger the enumerated result the more *allocations* it will perform, though even at worst case they are minimal.

<sub>***Note*** : If you want to reduce allocations in your code, then it's best to stay away from growing buffers and the magical beasts that cause them</sub>